# How to copy a file to the home directory of the user in .spec file

Tags: linux, rpm

Hi I am using Fedora 10 linux. I have created a .spec file now I want to write something which will make me able to to copy a file and store in Desktop of the user.

So how to do this.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPMs are installed per system, not per user, so you must put the file into the shared Desktop directory (and not the one of the user). I'm not sure where this directory is; check the documentation if your desktop framework (KDE or Gnome) and where Fedora configured the framework to put the shared files.

The actual installation is then to put the file in the right place inside the RPM.

If you really want to create an icon per user, then I suggest to ship a script which does it and which users should run once as a kind of "per user activation".